# adding items to DataTable via dictionary list VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, datatable

I am trying to add values to DataTable from dictionary. The key value pair for the dictionary is filled from the form. But the DataTable is only taking the last inserted value from the form. Why is it so?

```
Public Class dictionary
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim dictionary_ As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
        Dim value_ As String
        Dim key_ As String

        value_ = TextBox1.Text
        key_ = TextBox2.Text

        dictionary_.Add(value_, key_)

        Add_Data(dictionary_)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Add_Data(ByVal dic_ As Dictionary(Of String, String))
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("KEY")
        dt.Columns.Add("VALUE")

        For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In dic_
            dt.Rows.Add(item.Key, item.Value)
        Next

        dataGrid_.DataSource = dt

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you click the `Button`, you create a new `Dictionary` object, populate it with one data pair, create a new `DataTable` object, transfer that one data pair and then display that data. That means discarding the data already displayed. If you want the data to persist then you need to stop creating new objects and discarding the old ones all the time.

You may as well get rid of the `Dictionary` as it is pointless. You only need the `DataTable`. Create a single `DataTable` at the outset and bind that to the grid. You can then just add each data pair to the `DataTable` as you read it and it will automatically appear in the grid, as that's the point of binding.

Comment: can you please show the code, how to do it?